# Compare data between two tables and update value in another row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table named 'Master_Table' with column 'Asset Number'.

I would like to loop through that column to see if each value is in another table ('Table 'Daily' column 'Asset Number') then update column 'Found' on the 'Master_Table'.

I managed to loop through a column and check the other table. How do I update a column based on results?

```
Sub updateMasterColumns() 'strCol As String)

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("Master_Table[Asset Number]")
    
    For Each cell In rng
    
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(cell, Worksheets("Daily").ListObjects("DailyDump").ListColumns("Asset Number").Range, 0)) Then
            Debug.Print "Value exists"
        Else
            Debug.Print "Value does not exist"
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

I need it to be table-column specific as the table is growing on a daily basis.

Comment: Sounds like you can do this with a formula. Is VBA needed?

Comment: @BigBen unfortunately yes at the moment we did have so many vlookups that every time I change something it took at least a minute to update. wanted to do all the edits and then update later.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using tables (List Objects), I copied this function I built to lookup table values. Maybe it's overkill for you, but it works well.

Bear in mind result can = "".

```
Function getValueFromTable(theTable As ListObject, lookupValue As String, referenceCol As String, retrieveCol As String) As String
'index/match to retrieve a value from a table, given another value
    
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
    
        Dim Result As String
        
        On Error Resume Next 'ensures result returns no string when match not found
        Result = .index(theTable.ListColumns(retrieveCol).DataBodyRange, .Match(lookupValue, theTable.ListColumns(referenceCol).DataBodyRange, 0))
        
        'because some results are stored as numbers so string value will not find
        If Result = "" And IsNumeric(lookupValue) Then
            Result = .index(theTable.ListColumns(retrieveCol).DataBodyRange, .Match(CLng(lookupValue), theTable.ListColumns(referenceCol).DataBodyRange, 0))
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        
    End With
    
    getValueFromTable = Result

End Function
```